# Choose side of a die then roll

Tags: php, html

Write a program that lets the user choose how many sides a die
has and print a random roll with the appropriate maximum
values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>NumberOfFace</title>
</head> 
<body>
<?php

 print <<<HERE
 <h3>How many Face you want for your Dice</h3>
 <form action="" method="post">

 <input type="text" name="numFace" value="$numFace"/>
 <input type="submit" >

HERE;



$roll=rand(1,$numFace=filter_input(INPUT_POST, "numFace"));
print<<<HERE

  <p>you rolled a $roll.</p>
  <p>
  <img src="die$roll.png"
  alt=die="die: $roll"/>

  </p>

  HERE;
  ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm getting this  Warning: rand() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\numFaces.php on line 21

Comment: Read the error; there is no numerical value given but a string... Input a number in the text field and/or cast the value to a numerical (integer) value. Why assigning btw, as you don't use the variable afterwards?

Comment: Also, note that [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) generates a better random value than `rand()`.

Comment: thanx it works I have changed  text to number